# How to remove non-matching DocuSign generic template anchor field from signing document c#?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am sending the document in an envelope to sign along with the template Id to be applied. In this case, I have defined `SignHere` tabs for 10 signers using `AnchorString`. Sometimes the signer's count passed to sign the document would 2 sometime it would be 10.

What I am trying to achieve is, when there is only 1 matching signer then the rest of the `AnchorString` should be removed from documents, and space for those fields should also be managed accordingly.

Like, In below screen, there is only one signer passed for document as `Signer2`. So, in this case `Signer` and `Signer3` should be removed.

[image]

Is that possible to remove those non-matched `AnchorString` from document and manage the space accordignly using `c#` `DocuSign` `SDK`?

Do I need to set any `Envelope` property to handle that case or any other configuration need to be done while sending an `Envelope`?

Comment: do you want the document to be modified? or you just want to remove the matching of the string to tabs? if the latter - this can be done via the API, the former requires you to upload a new document, and modify the document using other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign does not remove information from the documents provided so it can not remove the anchor strings that you didn't use in your document. As a workaround you can create your anchor strings with a white font so it matches the background and it will not be noticeable to the user. This will still leave the empty space in the document, to remove the empty space you will need to provide different documents based on the scenario